# FastAPI and OpenCV background task

Tags: opencv, asynchronous, fastapi

I'd like to know if there is a way to run the code inside the endless loop (reading a frame using OpenCV and processing it) asynchronously? I'm considering using multithreading for this purpose (video capturing is running in background simultaneously with API) but before that I gave this a try.

```
class BackgroundRunner:
    def __init__(self):
        // OpenCV capture initialization
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    async def run_main(self):
       while True:
           ret, image_np = self.cap.read()

           if ret:
               # Process image 
           else: 
               # break

recognition_runner = BackgroundRunner()


# Starting recogntion runner on the startup
@app.on_event("startup")
async def app_startup():
    asyncio.create_task(recognition_runner.run_main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at this library called fastapi-utils? 
https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/repeated-tasks/

They have a repeated task annotation which with your code, you could adapt and use in the following way potentially:

```py
class BackgroundRunner:
    def __init__(self):
        # OpenCV capture initialization
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.processing = False  # variable to track whether a loop is in progress

    async def process(self):
       # remove the while True as this action will be repeated
       # while True:
       if self.processing:
           return
       self.processing = True
       ret, image_np = self.cap.read()

       if ret:
           # Process image 
       else: 
           # break
       self.processing = False

recognition_runner = BackgroundRunner()


# Starting recogntion runner on the startup
@app.on_event("startup")
@repeat_every(seconds=0.1)
async def app_startup():
    await recognition_runner.process()
```

Comment: +1, this is helpful, and it works, but I realized I have one more problem. Even though I can process my images this way at the same time I want to play the video and that will block I/O operations. I guess I'll need to break this into multithreading/multiprocessing tasks.

Comment: @Serjuice it does sound like multithreading will be a better suit for you the code in this answer will work out if you can read your input asynchronously and whatever code you have in the if block to process that image can be done asynchronously, otherwise you will end up blocking the http processing